# Why is my app's notification getting cleared automatically?

Tags: android, android-notifications

According to android documentation,

> A notification remains visible in the notification drawer until dismissed by the app or the user.

But why my notification is getting cleared by itself? My code is something like this

```
public class Worker extends Service{

    private final int notification_id=((int)(Calendar.getInstance().getTimeInMillis())%Integer.MAX_VALUE);
    private final String channel_id="STORAGE_ORGANIZER_DUPLICATE_CONTENT_EXTRACTOR_SERVICE_NOTIFICATION";

    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
        final NotificationManagerCompat notificationManager = NotificationManagerCompat.from(this);
        final NotificationCompat.Builder notification_builder=
            new NotificationCompat.Builder(this, channel_id)
                    .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.storage_icon)
                    .setContentTitle(getString(R.string.duplicate_content_extractor_notification_msg1))
                    .setProgress(1,0,true)
                    .setPriority(NotificationCompat.PRIORITY_DEFAULT)
                    .setOngoing(true);

    startForeground(notification_id,notification_builder.build());

    new Thread(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    // some long running work
                    Intent remover_intent=new Intent(
                        DuplicateContentExtractorService.this,
                        DuplicateContentExtractorServiceStopperService.class
                    );
                    PendingIntent remover_pendingIntent=PendingIntent.getService(
                        DuplicateContentExtractorService.this,
                        (int)Calendar.getInstance().getTimeInMillis() % 9999,
                        remover_intent,
                        PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT
                    );
                    stopForeground(false);
                    notification_builder.setOngoing(false);
                    notification_builder.setDeleteIntent(remover_pendingIntent);
                    notificationManager.notify(notification_id,notification_builder.build());

                }
    }).start();
}
```

Comment: What is api version that you tested it?

Comment: My API is 28(Pie), but this problem is occurring on Lolipop also.
I am testing it on API 28, the one I mentioned

Comment: Did you register that service in manifest file?

Comment: sure. It is working properly, but it is getting cleared automatically (without explicit clear)

Answer (score 0):

you need to set `notification_builder.setOngoing(true);` to true like

```
public class Worker extends Service{

    private final int notification_id=((int)(Calendar.getInstance().getTimeInMillis())%Integer.MAX_VALUE);
    private final String channel_id="STORAGE_ORGANIZER_DUPLICATE_CONTENT_EXTRACTOR_SERVICE_NOTIFICATION";

    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
        final NotificationManagerCompat notificationManager = NotificationManagerCompat.from(this);
        final NotificationCompat.Builder notification_builder=
            new NotificationCompat.Builder(this, channel_id)
                    .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.storage_icon)
                    .setContentTitle(getString(R.string.duplicate_content_extractor_notification_msg1))
                    .setProgress(1,0,true)
                    .setPriority(NotificationCompat.PRIORITY_DEFAULT)
                    .setOngoing(true);

    startForeground(notification_id,notification_builder.build());

    new Thread(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    // some long running work
                    Intent remover_intent=new Intent(
                        DuplicateContentExtractorService.this,
                        DuplicateContentExtractorServiceStopperService.class
                    );
                    PendingIntent remover_pendingIntent=PendingIntent.getService(
                        DuplicateContentExtractorService.this,
                        (int)Calendar.getInstance().getTimeInMillis() % 9999,
                        remover_intent,
                        PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT
                    );
                    stopForeground(false);
                    notification_builder.setOngoing(true);
                    notification_builder.setDeleteIntent(remover_pendingIntent);
                    notificationManager.notify(notification_id,notification_builder.build());

                }
    }).start();
}
```

Comment: But that will make the notification unclear-able. I just want it to be there as long as user doesn't clear it explicitly.

Comment: if you tap on it,it will clear automatically if setongoing in set to false.

Comment: I am not doing anything. After unlocking the phone, i don't see any notification.

Comment: @NowroseMuhammadRagib Probably because your app is in the foreground